# Is it possible to "merge" two rows in the result set of a SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking at a query that outputs something like the following:

```
Group | Date 1     | Value 1 | Date 2      | Value 2
------+------------+---------+-------------+--------
    A | 2011-06-15 | 105     | NULL        | NULL
    A | NULL       | NULL    | 2011-06-16  | 107
    B | 2011-06-18 | 567     | NULL        | NULL
    B | NULL       | NULL    | 2011-06-20  | 525
```

What I want is to "flatten" these results by group - sort of like a `COALESCE` by row:

```
Group | Date 1     | Value 1 | Date 2      | Value 2
------+------------+---------+-------------+--------
    A | 2011-06-15 | 105     | 2011-06-16  | 107
    B | 2011-06-18 | 567     | 2011-06-20  | 525
```

Note that there will only ever be 2 rows per group; this isn't dealing with an arbitrary number of data points, it's essentially a "before and after" query.

Is it possible to do this in a **single** pass?  (There is a large amount of data in the results).  That means:

- **No** temp tables, table variables, or similar intermediate steps (CTEs are fine);
- **No** joining to itself, i.e. the obvious solution of getting the `MIN` and `MAX` in one query and then joining to those dates to get the values.  As mentioned above, this is the result set of an expensive query, and I am trying very hard not to double the load.

I know that I could technically do this with a cursor, but I'd really *really* prefer not to unless somebody can prove to me that it is faster than any set-based option.

P.S. Please note that for group "B", Value 2 is lower than Value 1.  I've done this explicitly to demonstrate why a single `GROUP BY` which takes the `MIN` and `MAX` of both dates and values isn't going to produce the expected results.  The values have to be correlated to the dates.

Comment: You should review your data structure

Comment: @Nico: Useless comment. As I explained twice in the post, this is the *output* of a query, not data sitting in a table. It's coming from standard, run-of-the-mill, normalized row-level transactional data. Essentially it's a pivot query, except that the pivot values aren't constant.

Comment: Where does the 525 in desired group B Value 2 come from? I don't understand its relation to the original values in group B (NULL and 589)

Comment: With the data given by you, the `GROUP BY` approach would work just fine, so I don't understand your comment regarding correlation to the dates.

Comment: @Remus: It comes from a typo.  Corrected. :)

Comment: @Lucero: I apologize, there was an inconsistency on account of the anonymization. Value 2 is **not** guaranteed to be higher than Value 1, although Date 2 will always be after Date 1.

Comment: Is there only ever going to be one value per column, per group that won't be null? In that case the group by "Group" with Max on each column would eliminate the nulls.

Comment: @Ray: No, although your comment made me realize that I kind of screwed up the example when I was writing the question.  Going to delete this while I fix it... (apologies to everyone else)

Comment: @Aaronaught, since this question is open again, you may want to fix the question. Also please have a look at my answer which may actually be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you always get pairs in the `Group`s, you can do a `GROUP BY [Group]` and for each of the 4 columns select the `MAX()` (which will basically take the non-null value).

**Edit:** if you have a dataset with the columns "Group", "Date" and "Value" and want to merge those so that you have the "Group", "Date 1", "Value 1", "Date 2" and "Value 2" columns, use this (the first CTE represents the test data):

```
WITH Results AS (
    SELECT 'A' [Group], CONVERT(datetime, '2011-06-15') [Date], 105 [Value]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' [Group], CONVERT(datetime, '2011-06-16') [Date], 107 [Value]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' [Group], CONVERT(datetime, '2011-06-18') [Date], 567 [Value]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' [Group], CONVERT(datetime, '2011-06-20') [Date], 525 [Value]
),
ResultsIndexed AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.[Group] ORDER BY r.[Date]) ix, r.* FROM Results r
)
SELECT r1.[Group], r1.[Date] [Date 1], r1.[Value] [Value 1], r2.[Date] [Date 1], r2.[Value] [Value 1]
    FROM ResultsIndexed r1
    JOIN ResultsIndexed r2 ON (r1.[Group] = r2.[Group]) AND (r2.[ix] = 2)
    WHERE r1.[ix] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want. If you just have two row per group, you may try this.

```
;WITH cte as
(
    -- You sql output here
    SELECT  *
    FROM    table
)
SELECT  a1.group,a1.date1,a1.value1,a2.date2,a2.value2
FROM    cte a1
INNER JOIN cte a2
 ON a2.date2 IS NOT NULL
 AND a1.group = a2.group
WHERE a1.date1 IS NOT NULL
```